# Ruby: calling .each on the output of IO.readlines is looping back

Tags: ruby

I open a file using `@file = IO.readlines(filename)`. Then shortly later I iterate through all the lines in the following method:

```
def symbolicate
  @file.each do |line|
    puts line
    type = get_type(line)
    add_label(line) if type == :label
  end
end
```

I end up getting a nil inside `get_type()` which is causing problems. In debugging I logged each line in the each block and discovered that the first line is coming up again at the end of the loop after all the lines have been read. I confirmed this using `each_with_index` -- I get one final iteration where the index is 0 again and the value of `line` is the first line of the file.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here but it seems straightforward that I shouldn't loop back like this. It is also confusing that I'm getting a nil inside the `get_type` method since the value of `line` is valid when I print it just before entering the method. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

edit: For debugging I tried the following:

```
def symbolicate
  count = 0
  @file.each do |line|
    puts count.to_s + ": " + line
    count += 1
    #same stuff as before here
  end
end
```

When I get to the loop around at the end, `count` becomes zero again, even though it was initialized outside of the .each loop and only ever gets incremented. How can this be?! Here's the output from the second code segment above (with printing the count variable along with the line):

```
0: @SCREEN
1: D=A
2: @current
3: M=D
4: @KBD
5: D=M
6: @KEYDOWN
7: D;JGT
8: (KEYUP)
9: @0
10: D=A
11: @current
12: A=M
13: M=D
14: @current
15: M=M+1
16: @KBD
17: D=M
18: @KEYUP
19: D;JEQ
20: (CHANGE)
21: @SCREEN
22: D=A
23: @current
24: M=D
25: @KBD
26: D=M
27: @KEYUP
28: D;JEQ
29: (KEYDOWN)
30: @0
31: D=!A
32: @current
33: A=M
34: M=D
35: @current
36: M=M+1
37: @KBD
38: D=M
39: @KEYDOWN
40: D;JGT
41: @CHANGE
42: 0;JMP
0: @SCREEN
```

As you can see even the `count` variable gets reset when the loop jumps back to the beginning

Comment: Where do you call symbolicate? Maybe there's an issue further up.

Comment: `initialize` just reads the file into `@file` and sets up some constants and empty instance variables. Then the real entry point for the class is `parse` which calls `symbolicate` first. So there's basically nothing upstream

Comment: You validated that by debugging (e.g. output the count field, or puts something as first thing to do (between `def symbolicate` and `count`)?

Comment: Just added the output of the debugging puts to the OP, I think that is what you were asking about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. The nil errors were unrelated to the re-looping - I was accidentally calling symbolicate() twice (hence the looping). The nil is because I was calling chomp!() which returns nil if it makes no changes (rather than returning the value of the chomped string as I expected.